# Mysql: possible to add constraint that prevents a one to many relation from having less than certain number of relations?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `user` table that has many, say `user_property` table, where the foreign `user_id` is stored in the `user_property` table.

Now is it possible to add constraint so that a user should have at least one user property? So when a user have five properties, he can delete it one by one, but when there is only one property left, he can not delete it? I tried Googling but I am not even sure what is the search keyword for this.

The reason is, I want to avoid checking if a user have one property remaining only from the application layer, because it reads from replica, the read and write might not be synchronized, and on certain condition the user might accidentally delete all properties.

Any suggestion or different approaches is appreciated.

Comment: I'm upivoting because it's an interesting question. The only thing I can think of is a trigger. If you were on Firebird, you could possibly do it using SQL in a CHECK constraint. Deadly functionality which I would like to see in PostgreSQL and MySQL, but since you're on MySQL, I guess a trigger is the way to go

Comment: Generally, unless there are legal requirements to do so, you'd be ill advised in allowing users to delete data. In most cases, a soft delete is preferable (e.g. a flag column that can be set to 'deleted', say)

Comment: You should have a look at the creation of a user too. If you create a user, you **must** add at least add one property before you commit otherwise the constraint would be violated and you couldn't add a new user.

Comment: @ h.m.i13 yes it already is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a constraint.  The problem is handling new users.  You cannot insert a new user, because it has no properties.  You cannot insert a new property, because the user reference is not valid.  Ouch!

One solution involves triggers.  The idea is the following:

1. Add to the the `users` table a column for the number of current properties.
2. Add to the `users` table a column for the maximum number of properties ever.
3. Default the two values to `0` for new users.
4. Add a check constraint (or trigger) that when the maximum is > 0 then the current number has to be > 0.

In any database, you need to implement the first two counts using triggers (on `user_property`).  MySQL does not support `check` constraints, so the last condition also requires a trigger.

Comment: FYI - CHECK constraints are supported in MySQL 8.0.16 and later: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: Anyway, a CHECK constraint can't solve this because CHECK constraints can't reference other rows. They only check columns within the context of a single row.

Comment: @BillKarwin . . . The CHECK constraint doesn't have to reference other rows.  It only needs to validate the columns in the `users` table.  Is that not clear in the answer?

Comment: Oh, I see. You'd have to write triggers on user_property to increment and decrement the counts in the users table. Sure, that would work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no constraint in SQL that does what you describe.

A foreign key constraint would ensure that every row in `user_property` must reference a row that exists in the `user` table.

But there is no constraint in SQL that does the reverse: ensure every `user` is referenced by at least one row in `user_property`.

A CHECK constraint has been mentioned by some other comments and answers. But a CHECK constraint can reference only columns of the same row. It can't reference other rows of the same table or different tables.

The most straightforward solution is to handle this in application code. That is:

- Implement a function that INSERTs to `user`, while making sure there's also an INSERT of the first row to `user_property`.
- Implement a function that DELETEs from `user_property`, but first check if it's would leave zero properties for the given user_id. If so, return an error instead of deleting the user property.

Implementing such data integrity rules in application code comes with a risk, of course. What if you have multiple apps that access the same database? You need to implement the same rules in different apps. Perhaps even in different programming languages. Sounds like a PITA.

Nevertheless, not all business rules can be implemented with simple SQL declarative constraints.